# Excel 2013 INDEX/MATCH Multiple

Tags: excel

I have 2 sheets: USERS and USERNAMES.

USERS has A:FIRST NAME, B:LAST NAME and a blank C:USERNAME (along with other fields)
USERNAMES has A:FIRST NAME, B:LAST NAME, C:USERNAME

I need to populate the USERNAME column in USERS by combining FIRST NAME-LAST NAME, then running a match to pull the corresponding USERNAME from USERNAMES.

I'm a novice Excel user.  I've done some researching, but haven't found the right function yet and I'm running out of time on the project.  Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way to do this is to create a new column to the left of A and B in the "USERSNAMES" sheet, and use that as your `VLOOKUP` key.

For example, move your existing data in "USERNAMES" to the right by one column, then create a new column A where A1 is `=B1&C1` and copy down. Then in "USERS", just set C1 to `=VLOOKUP(A1&B1, USERNAMES!A:D, 4, 0)` and copy down.

If you want to be more careful, use a separator when you concatenate in both sheets, for example: `A1&"_"&B1`. This will make sure "Alexa Smith" and "Alex Asmith" are differentiated.

Comment: If you can't add a new column to your first sheet for some reason, there are ways to accomplish this without the added column, but they are a bit more complicated. You can check out the suggestions here if you need them: http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2009/04/21/vlookup-on-two-columns/.

Comment: Thanks @Leekaiinthesky.  I have now created a C:FULL NAME column in each sheet.  I need to pull the D:Username into USERS from USERNAMES.  There are column headers on line 1.

Comment: Ok, did you get it to work? From your latest description, it sounds like you need to put `=VLOOKUP(C2, USERNAMES!C:D, 2, 0)` in D2 of USERS and copy down.

Comment: That did it, thank you so much.  Can you explain what the '2' and the '0' are doing in that formula?

Comment: You're welcome! '2' means the value you want to return is the second column of the table you've defined (C:D in your case). '0' (or, equivalently, FALSE in the documentation) means that your matched value has to be an exact match as opposed to an "approximate match" from an ordered range. That second one's a little hard to explain concisely, but see the documentation for VLOOKUP's [range_lookup] argument here (or within Excel, or anywhere else): https://support.office.com/en-in/article/VLOOKUP-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65.

Comment: Much appreciated!  Now I have to go research all the missing fields!  Grrr.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unclear on your exact question, but here are helpful lookup methods:

If you're looking up a value and what you need is to the right, use vlookup.

`=VLOOKUP(lookup_value, range, index)`

If you're looking up a value and what you need is to the left:

`=INDEX(range, (MATCH(lookup_value, range))`

And I think you're asking for how to add two strings?  You can use:

`=CONCATENATE(value, value)`

Or you can concatenate with &, so '="Hello"&" "&"World"`or '=A1&" " B1` would give you Hello World or whatever is in those cells.

Comment: Hm, I have 2 sheets, each with First Name, Last Name in separate columns.  Sheet 1 needs to pull the USERNAME from Sheet 2, based on the combination of First Name + Last Name from both sheets